# Where is Toorum?

Tags: legend-of-grimrock

From what I understand, to achieve the Buddies with Toorum achievement, I need to

> 1. Find Toorum's remains.
>  2. Use them on a healing crystal to resurrect him.

However, I don't know how to accomplish that first step. A map would be helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find Toorum's remains on Level 10 in the Caverns Northwest of the Map.
There should be a Button on a pillar next to a hole.
Then a Wall should open, not far from the Pillar and you'll find an Axe, some more Loot, 1 more of his Notes and his remains which you can then revive on the Crystal.

Comment: This site has a picture of the location, see Secret #4.  http://www.gamebanshee.com/legendofgrimrock/secrets/secrets_level10.php#null